GroupMe Push Setup
I am trying to follow the instructions listed on the GroupMe Website to enable my python program to receive real-time messages from a group. In step 2 of the process the response I got was

'successful': False, 'error': '401:1c5k4zq1mycffe161kgqp13gnvvn:Unknown client'

instead of

"successful":true

similarly it returned

'subscription': '/user/'

instead of

"subscription":"/user/1000112"

I tried the following code with and without
json=

import requests

s = requests.Session()

r=s.post('https://push.groupme.com/faye', json={
    "channel":"/meta/subscribe",
    "clientId":"1c5k4zq1mycffe161kgqp13gnvvn",
    "subscription":"/user/<userid>",
    "id":"2",
    "ext":
      {
        "access_token":"SECRET_CODE",
        "timestamp":1322556419
      }
  })

print(r.json())

Any suggestions?
Thank you so much

What was the error?  You removed it above.  And did you actually supply a user ID?  Did you just shroud it in the example?

What comes after 'successful': False, 'error': seems important. Please include the whole result.

I aded the error message, thank you for pointing that out

I did not supply a user ID, do you know how I would determine the correct user ID?

I think first you have to register (but I don't know where) to get own access_token and own client_ID. If you use client_ID from tutorial then it may not work because it can be fake number. And someone else may create own channel and he/she may gives you his/her user_id which you can use to access his/her channel. BTW: I expect that during registration it may ask for your url because oAUTH shows https://YOUR_CALLBACK_URL/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN. I think it can work similar to other API - it expect that you will run it as web page.

First you have to run Handshake and it gives you client_id
import requests

data = [
    {
        "channel": "/meta/handshake",
        "version": "1.0",
        "supportedConnectionTypes": ["long-polling"],
        "id": "1"
    }
]

url = 'https://push.groupme.com/faye'
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
data = response.json()

print(response.text)

#for message in data:
#    for key, val in message.items():
#        print(f'{key}: {val}')

client_id = data[0]['clientId']

Next you have to use this client_id in all other requests.

Next you have to login on https://dev.groupme.com (using the same login and password as on https://groupme.com) and create Application to get ACCESS TOKEN
For test you may need to create own group channel - and it will have function to generate sharing link like https://groupme.com/join_group/101707363/f0RF78na and number 101707363 will be needed to subscribe this channel.
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'YfXp........'    # from Application created on dev.groupme.com
client_id = data[0]['clientId']  # from Handshake
group_id = 101707363             # from sharing link

timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())

data = [
    {
        "channel": "/meta/subscribe",
        "clientId": client_id,
        "subscription": f"/group/{group_id}",
        "id": "2",
        "ext": {
            "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
            "timestamp": timestamp,
        }
    }
]

url = 'https://push.groupme.com/faye'
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
data = response.json()

print(response.text)

#for message in data:
#    for key, val in message.items():
#        print(f'{key}: {val}')

And later you can send requests for data - but documentation suggests to use websockets for this. With normal requests it waits until it gets new data or it is timeouted. And it blocks all code.
data = [
    {
        "channel": "/meta/connect",
        "clientId": client_id,
        "connectionType": "long-polling",
        "id": "3"
    }
]    

url = 'https://push.groupme.com/faye'
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
data = response.json()

print(response.text)

#for message in data:
#    for key, val in message.items():
#        print(f'{key}: {val}')

And this may need to run in loop to get when you (or someone else) send messages on your group channel (created for test).
At this moment I get only message that I'm typing on my group channel but I still don't get messages. Maybe it needs to increate id in every request.

My full code for tests:
You have to create own group to get own sharing link with number for group_id
import requests
import datetime

def handshake():
    print('--- Step 1: Handshake ---')

    data = [
        {
            "channel": "/meta/handshake",
            "version": "1.0",
            "supportedConnectionTypes": ["long-polling"],
            "id": "1"
        }
    ]

    url = 'https://push.groupme.com/faye'
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    data = response.json()

    print('- data -')
    print(response.text)
    for key, val in data[0].items():
        print(f'{key}: {val}')

    client_id = data[0]['clientId']
    print('client_id:', client_id)

    return client_id
    
def subcribe_user_channel(client_id, user_id, ACCESS_TOKEN):
    print('--- Step 2: Subscribe to the user channel ---')

    timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    print(timestamp)

    data = [
        {
            "channel": "/meta/subscribe",
            "clientId": client_id,
            "subscription": f"/user/{user_id}",
            "id": "2",
            "ext": {
                "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
                "timestamp": timestamp, # 1322556419, 
            }
        }
    ]

    #print( datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1322556419) )
    # 1322556419 == 2011-11-29 09:46:59

    url = 'https://push.groupme.com/faye'
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    data = response.json()

    print('- data -')
    print(response.text)
    for messagein in data:
        for key, val in message.items():
            print(f'{key}: {val}')
    
def subscribe_group_channel(client_id, group_id, ACCESS_TOKEN):
    print('--- Step 2: Subscribe to the user channel ---')

    timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    print(timestamp)

    data = [
        {
            "channel": "/meta/subscribe",
            "clientId": client_id,
            "subscription": f"/group/{group_id}",
            "id": "2",
            "ext": {
                "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
                "timestamp": timestamp, # 1322556419, 
            }
        }
    ]

    url = 'https://push.groupme.com/faye'
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    data = response.json()

    print('- data -')
    print(response.text)
    for message in data:
        for key, val in message.items():
            print(f'{key}: {val}')
        
def poll_data(client_id):
    print('--- Step 4: Poll for data ---')
    print('# it can hang and wait for data if there is no data at this moment')

    data = [
        {
            "channel": "/meta/connect",
            "clientId": client_id,
            "connectionType": "long-polling",
            "id": "3"
        }
    ]    

    url = 'https://push.groupme.com/faye'
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    data = response.json()

    print('- data -')
    print(response.text)
    for message in data:
        for key, val in message.items():
            print(f'{key}: {val}')

# --- main ---
    
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'YfX..........' # from `Application` created on dev.groupme.com
#user_id  = '1000112'          # ???
group_id = '101707363'         # from sharing link: https://groupme.com/join_group/101707363/f0RF78na

client_id = handshake()
#subscribe_user_channel(client_id, user_id, ACCESS_TOKEN)
subscribe_group_channel(client_id, group_id, ACCESS_TOKEN)

while True:
    poll_data(client_id)


Thank you so much, I would not have figured that out on my own
